# filter assignee list in jira based on organization chart

Tags: groovy, jira, scriptrunner-for-jira

I have an organization like this:

TeamA, TeamB, TeamC and TeamD
each team has a leader and team member
I want to filter assignees in one project based on this condition :
Leaders can assign tasks to team members themselves and other leaders
Also, Team members can assign tasks just to the leader or other members of the team

How can we filter assignee list users based on this structure?

I write a code in customer picker script runner and using user filter to filter results, it works for filter groups but cannot filter based on the query
as the sample I mentioned B2B groupname

```
import com.atlassian.jira.avatar.Avatar;
import com.atlassian.jira.bc.user.search.UserSearchParams;
import com.atlassian.jira.bc.user.search.UserSearchService;
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor;
import com.atlassian.jira.user.ApplicationUser;
import com.atlassian.jira.user.UserFilter;
import com.onresolve.scriptrunner.canned.jira.fields.model.PickerOption;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import groovy.sql.Sql;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Driver;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.util.Properties;
import com.atlassian.core.util.ClassLoaderUtils;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.CustomFieldManager;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.fields.CustomField;
import com.atlassian.jira.event.type.EventDispatchOption
//Query connection

def driver = "org.postgresql.Driver";
def url = "jdbc:postgresql://ip:5432/namedb";
def username = "sample";
def password = "sample";
Class dbClass = ClassLoaderUtils.loadClass(driver, this.class);
Driver driverInstance = (Driver) dbClass.newInstance();
DriverManager.registerDriver(driverInstance);
Properties info = new Properties();
info.put("user", username);
info.put("password", password);
Connection connection = driverInstance.connect(url, info);
def sql = new Sql(connection)
def String m_assignee = '';
def String tgm_assignee = '';

//get username login
def userinfousername = ComponentAccessor.getJiraAuthenticationContext().getLoggedInUser().getUsername()

//define paramters for get user object
def issueManager = ComponentAccessor.getIssueManager()
def issueService = ComponentAccessor.getIssueService()

//sql query 
def sqlstr = "select managername,generalid  from mcigeneralname l where l.generalid in (select   generalid  from mcigeneralname where jiraaccount="+userinfousername+')'

 
def userSearchService = ComponentAccessor.getComponent(UserSearchService)
def userManager = ComponentAccessor.userManager
def avatarService = ComponentAccessor.avatarService
def authenticationContext = ComponentAccessor.jiraAuthenticationContext
def groupManager = ComponentAccessor.groupManager
 
def userFilter = new UserFilter(true, null, ['B2B', 'B2B'])
def userSearchParams = new UserSearchParams.Builder().allowEmptyQuery(true).filter(userFilter).maxResults(30).build()


 
search = { String inputValue ->
    userSearchService.findUsers(inputValue, userSearchParams)
}
 
/*
 * Retrieve the user from internal storage (we store the key). Return them if they still exist, regardless of
 * their group membership.
 */
getItemFromId = { String id ->
    userManager.getUserByKey(id)
}
 
/*
 * The user is still "valid" if they are a member of either of the below-mentioned groups, otherwise they become "disabled".
 */
validate = { ApplicationUser user ->
    groupManager.getGroupNamesForUser(user).intersect(['B2B', 'B2B'])
}
 
renderItemViewHtml = { ApplicationUser user ->
    user.displayName
}
 
renderItemTextOnlyValue = renderItemViewHtml
 
toOption = { ApplicationUser user, Closure<String> highlight ->
    def remoteUser = authenticationContext.getLoggedInUser()
 
    new PickerOption(
        value: user.key,
        label: user.displayName,
        html: highlight(user.displayName, false),
        icon: avatarService.getAvatarURL(remoteUser, user, Avatar.Size.SMALL)?.toString()
    )
}
```

Comment: show some code..

Comment: I edit my question and insert code